# Using NullIF and Coalesc in SQL vs Calculated Column w Case Logic in BI Tool (Tibco Spotfire Analyst)

Tags: sql, expression, coalesce, tibco, nullif

In our BI tool (Tibco Spotfire Analyst) we further create columns by adding Calculated Columns that typically have case logic expression to calculate desired output based on dataset queried from SQL.

The overall problem I am trying to solve is performance - long loading times when Tibco does a on demand query.

While this works, when we are loading significant amounts of data into the BI tool this slows down performance with numerous calculated columns.

I feel like we could more efficiently do the same calculations within the SQL in the Information Link in Tibco using some combination of NULLIF and COALESC.

Here is sample data, and a typical Case logic we use:

[Sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7hXYM.png)

Here is the desired output of above Case logic:

[Desired output for sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TeswB.png)

I haven't yet successfully figured out how to incorporate this same desired output into the SQL within the linked Information Link in Tibco report.  It seems like a combo of NULLIF and COALESC could work.

Any suggestions?

SELECT

(NULLIF(COALESCE(finalscore,
initialscore), 0.00)) AS [Scores]

FROM
scorecte

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: coalese is nearly unlimited paramaters... so coalesce(column1,column2,0.00) would give you column 1 when it's populated, column2 when it's populated, 0.00 when neither are populated.  however, this assumes column1 and column two are numeric data types. of the same type as 0.00

Comment: Using Redshift.

Comment: or just stop at the coalesce(column1, column2) if you want null returned if both are "Null"

Comment: Thanks @xQBert.  While I do want a null return if both are "Null", I also want to default to column1 if there are values in both column1 & column2 (regardless if the values are the same or different).

Comment: that's what coalesce does returns the first non-null value in a series.  So coalesce(column1, column2) will return column1 when not null and ignore the rest, return column2 if not null when column1 is null and when both are null return null.  I'm confused on your need if coalese isn't doing what you need.